# TaskList Can not find Child Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm using tasklist to find a windows with a specific title, but it seems it doex not work if target window is a child from main application. I'm using it On Eset Smart to find Activation product window, But Tasklist as I told can not detect this child window.

```
tasklist /fi "WINDOWTITLE eq Product Activation - ESET Smart Security"
```

How can I fix it? (if any)

Comment: Not enough info there to show what the application and windows are.

Comment: Use `tasklist /v >file.txt` and see if the window is in the list.  On some occasions the window title isn't quite what you expect it to be.

Comment: it can not find it, there is a window with (Product Activation - ESET Smart Security) title but there is nothing about it in file.txt by tasklist !

Comment: Are there any windows attributed to the eset process?  It may not have a title like the one you see.

Comment: NirSoft WinLister can list the windows but tasklist can not :(